# Как обратиться к каждому элементу исходной матрицы в Python?

Tags: python, csv, матрицы

У меня есть код который работает с матрицей находящейся в файле и работает с кодами module_1 module_2 и module_3

```
import csv
from matplotlib.pyplot import matshow, show
from module_1 import task_1
from module_2 import task_2
from module_3 import task_3
def read(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as file:
        r = list(csv.reader(file))
    for x in range(len(r)):
        for y in range(len(r[x])):
            r[x][y] = int(r[x][y])
    return r
def write(matrix, name = "result.csv"):
    with open(name, 'w') as file:
        for x in range(len(matrix)):
            for y in range(len(matrix[x])):
                if y == len(matrix[x]) - 1:
                    file.write(str(matrix[x][y]) + "\n")
                else:
                    file.write(str(matrix[x][y]) + " ")
t1 = task_1(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t1)):
    print(t1, end='\n')
print('\n')
t2 = task_2(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t2)):
    for y in range(len(t2[x])):
        print(t2[x][y], end=' ')
    print()
t3 = task_3(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t3)):
    print(t3[x], end='\n')
print('\n')
write(t2)
matshow(t2)
show()
```

module_1 меняет матрицу на нули

```
def task_1(m): 
    d = [0]*len(m)
    return d
```

И происходит вывод:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Но мне нужно чтобы был вывод:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Так же и в module_3 он удаляет последние 4 строки матрицы:

```
def task_3(m):
    return m[:-4]
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

А нужно:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

Входные данные в файле tekst.csv

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2
1,3,5,7,9,7,5,3
3,1,5,3,2,6,5,7
1,7,5,9,7,3,1,5
2,6,3,5,1,7,3,2
```

Comment: А как связан заголовок с самой задачей? В заголовке как обратиться к элементу матрицы, внутри про форматирование вывода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **1)**

Сразу же в глаза бросается тот факт, что Вы обращаетесь к таблице несколько раз. Это крайне неэффективно по времени и по памяти (вы постоянно преобразовываете таблицу в список). Обратитесь к ней в самом начале и передайте ей, например, переменную `TABLE`. Для повторяющихся переменных также советую использовать константы, описать их вначале вашей программы. Например, присвоить переменной `TABLE_NAME` имя таблицы с расширением `.csv`, т.е. `TABLE_NAME = 'tekst.csv'`

### **2)**

Измените функции `task_1`, `task_2` и `task_3`, чтобы в них происходило окончательное создание матриц. Таким образом, функция будет возвращать полноценный список с столбцами и строками.

### **3)**

Замените громоздкий цикл для функций `def write()` и `def read()`.

В данном случае я имею в виду заменить цикл внутри `write()` на:

```
ROWS = [(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)] 
# () - ЭТО ОБЪЕКТ SET (можете прочитать по нему документацию в интернете). КАЖДЫЙ SET - ЭТО ОДНА СТРОКА В ВАШЕЙ МАТРИЦЕ. В СОВОКУПНОСТИ ОНИ СОСТАВЛЯЮТ ПОЛНОЦЕННУЮ МАТРИЦУ

csvfile=open(TABLE_NAME, 'w', newline='')
obj=csv.writer(csvfile)
for row in ROWS:
   obj.writerow(row)
csvfile.close()
```

Цикл внутри `read()` заменить на:

```
with open(TABLE_NAME) as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    data_read = [row for row in reader]
```

### **4)**

Замените эту часть вашей программы:

```
t1 = task_1(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t1)):
    print(t1, end='\n')
print('\n')
t2 = task_2(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t2)):
    for y in range(len(t2[x])):
        print(t2[x][y], end=' ')
    print()
t3 = task_3(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t3)):
    print(t3[x], end='\n')
```

На это:

```
TABLE = read(TABLE_NAME)

matrix_t1 = task_1(TABLE)
matrix_t2 = task_2(TABLE)
matrix_t3 = task_3(TABLE)

print(*matrix_t1, sep = "  ")
print(*matrix_t2, sep = "  ")
print(*matrix_t3, sep = "  ")
```

Comment: Немного не догоняю, в каком месте мне надо вставить данный код ля вывода и что заменить, `TABLE = read("tekst.csv") ` добавить в самое начало кода или когда код начинает выводиться ?

Comment: @Александр я добавил пояснения в свой ответ

Comment: Я заменил вывод получается такой:
`0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 7, 3, 2]  [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 7, 5, 3]  [3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 6, 5, 7]  [1, 7, 5, 9, 7, 3, 1, 5]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: @Александр можете вставить весь ваш измененный код сюда, пожалуйста: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WuK4cBxVPdBxySm8dEwWk2XcU-w1xmEY?usp=sharing

Comment: А извините всё понял, что не так